# Coloring tr with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to color `tr` with `.click` event using jquery.

My code has no problem with coloring the first row which is static, but other rows, created with jQuery don't want to color.

I have no idea why is not working on other rows.

```
$(function () {
    $('tr').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("obarva");
    });
});
```

Here is my existing code: `http://jsfiddle.net/1mihcc/7okvbkg2/1/

Comment: sorry, but i didn't find it!

Answer (score 0):

That's because the elements are not in the DOM when you run the jQuery selector. Use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', 'tr', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("obarva");
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes i did that, and it works perfect in jsFiddle, but when I run same code from netbeans, coloring doesn't work. I have css in html and js as other file.